# What is negative property in the context of database design?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I read in scientific literature that lossy join is a negative property in relational database design. What is a negative property in the context of database design? Is there something called a positive property as well?

Comment: Can you quote the whole sentence? I think you mean "lossy join decomposition". And "negative property" just means that it's a bad thing to have such decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Lossy join really means a lossy *decomposition and join* operation. For example, given the following relation, R:

```
R
+-----+-----+
| a   | b   | 
|-----|-----|
| FOO | 100 | 
| FOO | 200 | 
| BAR | 100 | 
+-----+-----+
```

the following decomposition into new relations R1 and R2 would be "lossy" because it isn't possible to reconstruct the original tuples of R simply by joining R1 and R2.

```
R1         R2
+-----+    +-----+
| a   |    | b   |
|-----|    |-----|
| FOO |    | 100 |
| BAR |    | 200 |
+-----+    +-----+
```

"Lossy" means that information is lost after a decomposition and join.

In database design theory non-lossy decompositions are of interest when considering whether possible alternative database designs can faithfully represent the same information. Out of context it's not meaningful to say that lossiness is either a positive or negative thing - it's just a property that some decomposition-join may or may not have.